# How to cache ajax json object for use in chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using morris.js charts library and i currently use a ajax request to get a json object via php.

what i would like to do is cache the response and on loading the page if the json is already cached use that data instead of making another ajax call.

my understanding of ajax is limited and have tried `sessionStorage` but the function to generate the chart runs before the ajax has completed.

Any advice would be great

thanks

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
var getAreaData = (function () {
 var cache = {}; // results will be cached in this object

return function (callback) {
if (cache != null) { // if exist on cache
  callback(cache);
  return;
}
// doesn't exists on cache, make Ajax request and cache it
$.get(baseUrl+"/main/orderChannel",  function (data) { 
  cache= data; // store the returned data
  callback(data);
  console.log(data);
   });
 };    
})();

 getAreaData(function (data) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: any written code would be awesome?

Comment: now where do you create your chart? The data should be available in once it reached the console.log(data) inside your `getAreaData(function(data) { console.log(data); // <-- build your chart here });`

Comment: console.log just returns an empy object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using JQuery, you could make it yourself quite easy with the callbacks, and just use a promise to return. You could do it a bit more simple, like this for example:

```js
(function($) {
  
  function getAreaData(url) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    if (getAreaData.cache) {
      // call it at the next possible time
      setTimeout(function() { def.resolve(getAreaData.cache) }, 0);
      return def;
    }
    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
      // cache the result as a property of the getAreaData function
      getAreaData.cache = data;
      def.resolve(data);
    }).fail(def.reject);
    return def;
  }
  
  // uncomment this line to see how the cache would react when enabled
  //getAreaData.cache = { key: 'I am an object' };
  
  $.getAreaData = getAreaData;
  
})(jQuery);


$.getAreaData('#/items')
  .done(function(data) {
     console.log('I succeeded with ', data);
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
     console.log('I failed with ', error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, thats very nice! how would i access data   `console.log('I succeeded with ', data);`

Comment: @rob How do you mean? From there you would need to call the method that starts drawing your chart as far as I can read from your opening post

Comment: sorry i was being stupid there. one point i have noticed is when i refresh the page is still does the ajax call even through the cache is not empty?

Comment: @rob refresh means empty cache, as the cache here is just a property of the getAreaData function. If you really want to store the data, you should check into localStorage or depending on the size of your data, cookies... The cache here would help to make sure you only call the service once as long as your page is loaded (so clicking a button to redraw the chart would in that case simply reload the cache), once the page gets reloaded, no more cache in my current example